# Vue 3: Isn't the value of a component's prop that's bound to ref in the parent component updated immediately?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-props

I'm using Vue3's Composition API in a project that injects HTML code from a webpage (that's in my domain) into another webpage. I've made a simplified version of the real project's code base in this post.

There are 2 main components. The `App` and `Child`. The `Child` component is used in the `App` (parent component). The `Child` component contains a `<div>` in which HTML code of a another page is injected. And the `App` has a method, `changeUrl()` that will load another page. In the real project this is triggered by key releases, but for simplification I have a `<button>` displayed in the `App`.

The URL of the source of the webpage to be injected is in the `App` - stored in the ref `urlRef`. The `Child` has a prop called `sourceUrl` and that's bound to `urlRef`. When the button is clicked, `changeUrl` is triggered which sets URL to `urlRef.value` and calls the `Child`'s method to inject that HTML inside the respective `<div>`.

When I clicked the button I noticed that value of the prop `sourceUrl` is not updated immediately. How come?

Is my approach wrong?

Here's a screenshot of what it looks with the console on the side after I click the button:
[image]

Code of App.vue:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Child from './components/Child.vue';

const childComponentRef = ref(null);
const urlRef = ref("WebPageA.html");

const changeUrl = () => {
   urlRef.value = "WebPageB.html";
   console.log(`App: Button clicked to change url to ${urlRef.value}`);

   childComponentRef.value.injectHtml();
}
</script>

<template>
   <Child 
      ref="childComponentRef"
      :source-url="urlRef" 
   />

   <div class="card">
      <button type="button" @click="changeUrl">Change URL</button>
   </div>
</template>
```

Code of Child.vue:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  sourceUrl: String,
});

const injectHtml = async () => {
   console.log(`Child: Begin injecting! Source ${props.sourceUrl}`);

   try {
      const response = await fetch(props.sourceUrl);

      if (response.ok) {
         if (document.querySelector("#new-html-container")) {
            document.querySelector("#new-html-container").remove();
         }

         const tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
         tempDiv.id = "new-html-container";
         tempDiv.innerHTML = await response.text();
         
         document.querySelector("#container").appendChild(tempDiv);
      }
   } catch(error) {
      console.log("Error during injection");
      console.log(error);
   }
}

defineExpose({
   injectHtml,
});

onMounted(() => {
   injectHtml();
})
</script>

<template>
   <div>
      <h3>Here's the source url: {{ sourceUrl }}</h3>
   </div>

   <div id="container">
      <!-- the html will be injected here -->
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you check that call order of `watch` method and `injectHtml` method?

Comment: @leteu sorry, I don't understand your question. I haven't used a `watch` method

Comment: If you call your function `injectHtml` in the vue `watch` method with a getter function, then it will work: https://codesandbox.io/s/inject-html-pages-3wp4gf?file=/src/App.vue ... To call the watch method only once, I passed and check the props value in your async function. ;)